# Get nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json

How can I get the 'value' inside the 'cost'? Please help me, I just learned JSON from w3schools. I have tried, but it didn't work. My code for get the 'value' is in the bottom of the code.

```
 <p id="demo"></p>

 <script>
 var text='{ "rajaongkir":{
  "query":{
     "origin":"501",
     "destination":"114",
     "weight":1700,
     "courier":"jne"
  },
  "status":{
     "code":200,
     "description":"OK"
  },
  "origin_details":{
     "city_id":"501",
     "province_id":"5",
     "province":"DI Yogyakarta",
     "type":"Kota",
     "city_name":"Yogyakarta",
     "postal_code":"55000"
  },
  "destination_details":{
     "city_id":"114",
     "province_id":"1",
     "province":"Bali",
     "type":"Kota",
     "city_name":"Denpasar",
     "postal_code":"80000"
  },
  "results":[
     {
        "code":"jne",
        "name":"Jalur Nugraha Ekakurir (JNE)",
        "costs":[
           {
              "service":"OKE",
              "description":"Ongkos Kirim Ekonomis",
              "cost":[
                 {
                    "value":38000,  //<<<<<<  GET THIS VALUE
                    "etd":"4-5",
                    "note":""
                 }
              ]
           },
           {
              "service":"REG",
              "description":"Layanan Reguler",
              "cost":[
                 {
                    "value":44000,
                    "etd":"2-3",
                    "note":""
                 }
              ]
           },
           {
              "service":"SPS",
              "description":"Super Speed",
              "cost":[
                 {
                    "value":349000,
                    "etd":"",
                    "note":""
                 }
              ]
           },
           {
              "service":"YES",
              "description":"Yakin Esok Sampai",
              "cost":[
                 {
                    "value":98000,
                    "etd":"1-1",
                    "note":""
                 }
              ]
           }
        ]
     }
  ]}}';  
   obj=JSON.parse(text);
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=
   obj.rajaongkir.results[0].costs[0].cost[0].value;
   </script>
```

Comment: I love that you censored `w3sch**ls`

Comment: but I think it's become uncensored -_-

Comment: Learn to debug, log to console at every step `obj` then `obj.rajaongkir`. `console.log` in chrome or firefox will be very handy.

Comment: assuming `text` is parsed to JSON, then loop over the array of "costs" in  `text.rajaongkir.results.costs` and then get each item's cost...

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Looks fine to me, JSON is valid and the access to costs is correct. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Your code is perfect http://jsfiddle.net/x9nL9e4w/ How did you get this json? Using Ajax?

Comment: because there's line breaks on it, someone already answer it and I feel stupid right now haha.. Thanks for trying to help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is not a valid string literal. There are no line breaks allowed, unless you end every line with a `\`.

If you add these `\`, everything is fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/ec3n6f20/

Comment: I feel stupid haha.. Thanks for your help.. sorry I just learn about JSON

Answer (score 4):

Your input string is wrong

```
<p id="demo"></p>

 <script>
 var text='{ "rajaongkir":{ '
+ '  "query":{'
+'     "origin":"501",'
+'     "destination":"114",'
+'     "weight":1700,'
+'     "courier":"jne"'
+'  },'
+'  "status":{'
+'     "code":200,'
+'     "description":"OK"'
+'  },'
+'  "origin_details":{'
+'     "city_id":"501",'
+'     "province_id":"5",'
+'     "province":"DI Yogyakarta",'
+'     "type":"Kota",'
+'     "city_name":"Yogyakarta",'
+'     "postal_code":"55000"'
+'  },'
+'  "destination_details":{'
+'     "city_id":"114",'
+'     "province_id":"1",'
+'     "province":"Bali",'
+'     "type":"Kota",'
+'     "city_name":"Denpasar",'
+'     "postal_code":"80000"'
+'  },'
+'  "results":['
+'     {'
+'        "code":"jne",'
+'        "name":"Jalur Nugraha Ekakurir (JNE)",'
+'        "costs":['
+'           {'
+'              "service":"OKE",'
+'              "description":"Ongkos Kirim Ekonomis",'
+'              "cost":['
+'                 {'
+'                    "value":38000,'  //<<<<<<  GET THIS VALUE
+'                    "etd":"4-5",'
+'                    "note":""'
+'                 }'
+'              ]'
+'           },'
+'           {'
+'              "service":"REG",'
+'              "description":"Layanan Reguler",'
+'              "cost":['
+'                 {'
+'                    "value":44000,'
+'                    "etd":"2-3",'
+'                    "note":""'
+'                 }'
+'              ]'
+'           },'
+'           {'
+'              "service":"SPS",'
+'              "description":"Super Speed",'
+'              "cost":['
+'                 {'
+'                    "value":349000,'
+'                    "etd":"",'
+'                    "note":""'
+'                 }'
+'              ]'
+'           },'
+'           {'
+'              "service":"YES",'
+'              "description":"Yakin Esok Sampai",'
+'              "cost":['
+'                 {'
+'                    "value":98000,'
+'                    "etd":"1-1",'
+'                    "note":""'
+'                 }'
+'              ]'
+'           }'
+'        ]'
+'     }'
+'  ]}}';  
   obj=JSON.parse(text);
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=
   obj.rajaongkir.results[0].costs[0].cost[0].value;
   </script>
```

Comment: How is this a help? You don't even say what's wrong about this string.

Answer (score 1):

First parse `text` string to a [Json](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) structure

Then it's all up to combination of [each](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/forEach) functions and getters:

```
var input= JSON.parse(text);

input.results.forEach (function(result){
  result.costs.forEach (function(costEntity){
     console.log(costEntity.cost.value);
  });
});
```

But after running your code through Chrome console- it does not compile, even as a String, so first fix that:)

Comment: `text` is not even a valid string literal

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct but in Javascript we can't declare a string in several lines.

You have two workaround :

1. Make the string in only one line

   ```
   var text = '{...}';
   ```
2. Add a `\`at the end of each line

   ```
   var text='{ "rajaongkir":{ \
        "query":{ \
        ...
        "origin":"501", \
   }}}';
   ```
3. Wrap each line in `'` and add a `+` at the beginning

   ```
   var text='{ "rajaongkir":{ '
   + '  "query":{'
   ...
   + ']}}';
   ```